# Two tables vs one with a lookup table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In our application we have two forms. On the forms are an area for the user to add comments. These comments need to be stored in the database. Since there are two types of users and two forms I was thinking of having four tables:

`User1Form1Comments
 User2Form1Comments
 User1Form2Comments
 User2Form2Comments`

Each table would have the same columns.

However, I was also thinking of having one table with two lookup tables:

`Comments
 UserTypeLookupTable
 FormTypeLookupTables`

The lookup tables would basically just be an `Id` with a `Name`.

We could also do some sort of hybrid. For example, two tables with a single lookup table:

`Form1Comments
 Form2Comments
 UserTypeLookupTable`

Which approach would be best? Should I use another solution?

Comment: How about one table and no lookup tables, (Since their data is static any way)

Comment: @Magnus wouldn't that be denormalized?

Comment: Don't split the tables by user or comment. While I'm all for normalization, if this is all that would reference these tables then I'd go with a single table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one table to hold comments, and columns in that table to identify the user and purpose of the comments.  In other words, add a column to the table to identify the user, and another column to identify which form the comment belongs to.

Basically what you suggested with one table and two lookup values/tables.